# RMysql encoding utf8 issue

Tags: r

I am trying to make use of RMysql package to connect with mysql database and fetch data from it. While importing into R it is changing the encoding format from utf8 thus a records which is "Córdoba" in UTF-8 is returned as "CÃ³rdoba".

I have tried many things from few post from Stackflow but with no success.

I have tried to set the names as utf 8 using the command and few other thing as

```
dbGetQuery(mydb,'set character set "utf8"')
```

It looks that i am missing at something. Really looking for someone who can guide me to the resolution as it has become a show stopper for me.
Kindly help please.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is looking for the resolution to it, i would like to mention it.
After exporting the data from SQL into R either using dbGetQuery or dbSendQuery, function "**iconv**" can be executed on the table's vectors to convert it into utf8 format.
Bekow is the code example of extracting the data and converting it into utf8 format.

```
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from dim_survey_response_alignment")
alignfile = fetch(rs, n=-1)
alignfile <- subset(alignfile, select = c("attribute","response","aligned"))

alignfile$response <- iconv(alignfile$response,from = "UTF-8")
```

Enjoy Learning

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the same problem with:

```
dbSendQuery(conn, 'set character set "utf8"')
data <- dbReadTable( conn, "name")
```